# Plotting error from Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox plot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I am very new to Mathematica, so I might be doing something dumb here. I'm trying to make a graph of the following code and it keeps on giving me an error

```
P[θ_, φ_] := 2 Sin[θ (π/180)/2]^2 + {Sin[θπ/180]^2}/4 Abs[1 + Exp[-iφπ/180]];
Plot[{P[x, 30], P[x, 45], P[x, 60], P[x, 90]}, {x, θ, 180}]
```

attached is the code that I am trying to use and a visualization of what my graph is supposed to look like. (the functions in the photo and my code is supposed to be very slightly different)
[image: sample]

this is the error I keep on getting after pressing shift enter and attempting to plot.

> Plot::plln: Limiting value θ in {Charting`Private`pvar$4070,θ,180} is not a machine-sized real number.

Comment: you can't write `Plot[{P[x, 30], P[x, 45], P[x, 60], P[x, 90]}, {x, \[Theta], 180}]`  since `Theta` is not a number. What will `x` start from?

Comment: There are a few typing errors. Do `P[\[Theta]_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = 
  2 Sin[\[Theta] (\[Pi]/180)/2]^2 + (Sin[\[Theta] \[Pi]/180]^2)/4 Abs[
     1 + Exp[-I \[CurlyPhi] \[Pi]/180]];

Plot[{P[x, 30], P[x, 45], P[x, 60], P[x, 90]}, {x, 0, 180}] ` .

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:  `p[t_, f_] := 
 Module[{tt = t, ff = f}, 
  2 Sin[tt (\[Pi]/180)/2]^2 + {Sin[tt \[Pi]/180]^2}/4 Abs[
     1 + Exp[-I ff \[Pi]/180]]]

Plot3D[p[x, y], {x, 0, 180}, {y, 30, 90}]`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the typos.

```
P[θ_, φ_] := 2 Sin[θ (π/180)/2]^2 + {Sin[θ*π/180]^2}/4 Abs[1 + Exp[-I*φ*π/180]];
```

You made the following mistakes:

1. For complex $i$, use `I` not `i`
2. `θπ` is incorrect. It should be `θ*π`
3. Same `iφπ` is incorrect, replace with `I*φ*π`
4. In the plot function, `{x, θ, 180}` is incorrect. You need to specify a range for values of `x`, for instance `{x, 0, 180}`

Output after making the necessary changes attached.

```
Plot[{P[x, 30], P[x, 45], P[x, 60], P[x, 90]}, {x, 0, 180}]
```

[image]